# how to get all cell values from a table and converting in json with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

i have the following HTML code:

```
<table id="resultados" class="table table-checkable dataTable no-footer ">
<tbody>
    <tr id="Rhead">
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Código</th>
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Proveedor</th>
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Producto</th>
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Precio</th>
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Acciones</th>
        <th style="background-color: rgb(27, 197, 189);">Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="N1row">
        <td id="1menu">1</td>
        <td id="1menu">1</td>
        <td id="1menu">Ham Clasica</td>
        <td id="1menu">3</td>
        <td id="NCellRow1">
            <center><button id="N1button" onclick="ResponseTableButton(&quot;N1row&quot;)" class="envio btn btn-link-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></center>
        </td>
        <td id="1rowCellCantidad"><input type="text" id="N1rowInputCantidad" name="N1rowInputCantidad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="N3row">
        <td id="3menu">3</td>
        <td id="3menu">1</td>
        <td id="3menu">Ham Guayanesa</td>
        <td id="3menu">4.5</td>
        <td id="NCellRow3">
            <center><button id="N3button" onclick="ResponseTableButton(&quot;N3row&quot;)" class="envio btn btn-link-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></center>
        </td>
        <td id="3rowCellCantidad"><input type="text" id="N3rowInputCantidad" name="N3rowInputCantidad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="N4row">
        <td id="4menu">4</td>
        <td id="4menu">1</td>
        <td id="4menu">Ham New York</td>
        <td id="4menu">5.6</td>
        <td id="NCellRow4">
            <center><button id="N4button" onclick="ResponseTableButton(&quot;N4row&quot;)" class="envio btn btn-link-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></center>
        </td>
        <td id="4rowCellCantidad"><input type="text" id="N4rowInputCantidad" name="N4rowInputCantidad"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i need get each value each cell and even the input form value from table and converting it in formatting json and I can't find a way to do it

This would be the json format I need:

[image: JSON Format]

```
[ "N1row"={ 'codigo': '1', 'Proveedor': '1', 'Producto': 'Ham Clasica', 'Precio': '3', 'Cantidad': '4', }, "N3row"={ 'codigo': '3', 'Proveedor': '1', 'Producto': 'Ham Guayanesa', 'Precio': '4.5', 'Cantidad': '5', }, "N4row"={ 'codigo': '4', 'Proveedor': '1', 'Producto': 'Ham New York', 'Precio': '5.6', 'Cantidad': '6', } ]
```

Note: all row are generated dynamically, they can be N Row

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put the `<tr><th>` inside a `<thead>` tag instead of `<tbody>`

1. Get a reference to the TR that holds the headers.
2. Loop on it to get the header values, save them into an array.
3. Get a reference to the list of TRs in the table body `tbody`.
4. Loop on that list
5. for each member in the loop above (4) you start a new loop, on the values inside that specific `tr`.
6. For each member you find in (5) you know it's name, as it shoud have the name has the same index in the array you found in step (2).

I hope from here it is easy to just populate those key/values into a json object you instantiated before all those loops.